# how do I send post request with fetchAPI

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I have a simple 'username' , 'password' form in index.html, the thing is I would like to send a post request to 'login.php' (which only echoing 'hello' for the moment), but all examples about fetchAPI that I found are related to JSON. In one of my projects, I would like to post username to something like 'usercheck.php' and check for available username and write 'This username is available' '...is not available' by using fetchAPI. Im probably missing a syntax...
So the problem is im keep getting **405 (Method not allowed)**

**main.js**

```
const myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

e.preventDefault();

const username = document.querySelector('#inp_username').value;
//const password = document.querySelector('#inp_password').value;

fetch('login.php' , {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: {username: username}
})
.then((res) => res.text())
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);

})
})
```

**and my login.php**

```
<?php

echo 'hello';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend doesn't allow you to use POST. Make sure there is a route that allows POST in your backend.

Comment: Oh, i was using an extension 'live server' from VS Code, as you said I switched to 'xampp' then tried, it worked :) but the thing is i cant see request when I use google dev tools > Network tab like 'login.php' ... is it normal ?

Comment: I always use [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test sending http request, so I dont know how to properly use the networks tab